# Exactly when (in which NodeJS event loop phase) are a Readable stream's "data", "close" and "end" events emitted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-loop, node-streams

I thought I got a complete understanding of NodeJS event loop and its phases, but apparently not.

**When are the handlers of the "data", "close" and "end" event handlers executed? In which event loop phase or task queue?**

The question is straightforward, but let me explain what I expect and what I don't understand.

Let's consider the following code (Node 19).

```js
const stream = require('stream');

const readable = new stream.Readable({ read() {} });

// 1st PUSH
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate log 1'));
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick log 1'));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('Microtask log 1'));
readable.push(Buffer.from([1]));
console.log('Pushed data # 1');

// 2nd PUSH
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate log 2'));
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick log 2'));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('Microtask log 2'));
readable.push(Buffer.from([2]));
console.log('Pushed data # 2');

console.log('Attaching handlers....');
readable.on('data', data => console.log('Data received:', data))
    .on('end', () => console.log('End received'))
    .on('close', () => console.log('Close received'))
console.log('Handlers attached');

// 3RD PUSH
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate log 3'));
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick log 3'));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('Microtask log 3'));
readable.push(Buffer.from([3]));
console.log('Pushed data # 3');

// 4TH PUSH
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate log 4'));
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick log 4'));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('Microtask log 4'));
readable.push(Buffer.from([4]));
console.log('Pushed data # 4');

// NULL PUSH
setImmediate(() => console.log('Immediate log null'));
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick log null'));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('Microtask log null'));
readable.push(null);
console.log('Pushed null');

console.log('----END OF MAIN CODE----');
```

And here's the output:

```
Pushed data # 1
Pushed data # 2
Attaching handlers....
Handlers attached
Pushed data # 3
Pushed data # 4
Pushed null
----END OF MAIN CODE----
Next tick log 1
Next tick log 2
Data received: <Buffer 01>
Data received: <Buffer 02>
Data received: <Buffer 03>
Data received: <Buffer 04>
Next tick log 3
Next tick log 4
Next tick log null
End received
Close received
Microtask log 1
Microtask log 2
Microtask log 3
Microtask log 4
Microtask log null
Immediate log 1
Immediate log 2
Immediate log 3
Immediate log 4
Immediate log null
```

**I don't understand how can be the 3rd and 4th data event handlers executed before my 3rd and 4th nextTick handlers** event though I push data *after* I add my handlers to the nextTick queue.

For me, it's like not the `.push()` but the `.on('data')` call somehow inserts a "listener-like" stuff into the nextTick queue, and it stays there in that place for all future data events. So anything I push to the nextTick queue after attaching the data event handler will be executed *after* the event handler, as you can see. It doesn't make sense to me; I'd expect the `.push()` call to push the data event handler to the *end* of the nextTick queue.

What do I misunderstand here?

The "end" and "close" event handlers seem to make sense to me, since - as I can see - the `.push(null)` call pushes the handler to the end of the nextTick queue. However, **initially I thought that - at least the "close" handler - is executed in the separate macrotask queue of close handlers, which comes after the immediate queue, but seemingly it's not the case**, am I right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `.on("data")` does in fact create an event listener, and because at the time you do that there's already data there, the event handler will be queued to run.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, I do understand that. But after reading all the data by attaching the "data" handler, future calls to the handler are executed _before_ my 3rd and 4th nextTick handler (however the data are pushed _after_ adding these nextTick handlers). This is what I don't understand.

Comment: I'd suggest you have to go **study the nodejs stream code** because it's not uncommon that stream code will do something like `process.nextTick(processCloseEvent)` to force some event they are triggering to a future tick of the event loop.  And, exactly how they write that code will determine how it interacts with the event loop.  Question like these can only be answered through both experimentation and studying the code.  And, generally you should NOT rely on this level of scheduling detail in your code since it's clearly undocumented and can change.

Comment: Is there some real programming context or real code that this is relevant to (other than a theoretical/study question)?  Because if you disclosed that, then people could also offer better ways to code it that isn't sensitive to minute scheduling details in the stream code (which is what you should want).

Comment: @jfriend00 It's a theoretical question, I can't provide real-life code context. You are probably right with that one should not rely on this specific behavior. I just would like to understand it, because - for me - it doesn't fit into the documented constructs of the event loop.

Comment: Then, go study how each event you're interested in is triggered in the stream code.  That will probably explain how each one fits into the event loop phases.  And, the most difficult stuff about understand event loop ordering is that sometimes it matters where you are in the event loop phases when a new event is triggered because that affects how soon it will get processed or what it will get processed before or after.